# Как изменить стейт при условии? React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook

Подскажите как изменить состояние хука `setTime` в данном `onChange`:

```
const [ time, setTime ] = useState('');

onChange = event => {
  const re = /^[0-9\b]+$/    
  if (event.target.value === '' || re.test(event.target.value)) {
    setTime(this.setState({value: event.target.value}))
  }
}
```

В моем случае он выдает вполне логичную ошибку:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
```

Comment: Зачем использовать setState, если у Вас есть setTime? Меняйте состояние с помощью setTime

Comment: ошибка та же  и если используем `useTime` то у `(this.setState({value: event.target.value})` получаем `Argument type {value: string} is not assignable to parameter type number`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В хуках Вам не требуется писать `this` перед вызовом dispatcher'a `setTime`:

```
const [time, setTime] = useState("")

const onChange = event => {
  const value = event.target.value
  const regex = /^[0-9\b]+$/    
  if (value === "" || regex.test(value)) {
    setTime(value)
  }
}
```

*Так же изначально `initialState` у Вас равен пустой строке, а впоследствии Вы пытаетесь заменить его на объект с ключом `value`.*